# Modifier Particles System - no "Apply" button

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I'm trying to recreate something from a tutorial and at one point you have to apply a particles system you created to a mesh. the thing is, the apply button doesn't show. the person from the tutorial is using 2.78 and I use 2.79, but I don't think that is the reason. does anyone know what could be the cause of that? beste regards :)
[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72839/understanding-how-the-modifiers-panels-convert-button-affects-particle-systems. That should've been mentioned in tutorial, set type of emitter for the system as Object or Group

Comment: Can you attach the file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/